# Should I use OLS of fixed effects for this model?

Tags: r, regression

[image]

I'm trying to estimate this model on immigration levels I found in a paper and I'm not sure if they used OLS or fixed effects, it says that its a simple OLS but then mentions adding the country fixed effects. can someone help?